# neo4j docker image (vps managed with plesk), cannot assign certificates for secure bolt connection with Let's encrypt certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, neo4j, plesk

I'm trying to run neo4j community on a vps via a docker image managed with plesk.

I am however having issues configuring the SSL certificate so I can connect to it securely from nodejs.

Currently, the error I'm getting is quite straightforward in node:

```
Neo4jError: Failed to connect to server. 
Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have 
compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption 
setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused by: Server certificate is not trusted. If you trust the 
database you are connecting to, use TRUST_CUSTOM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES and add the signing 
certificate, or the server certificate, to the list of certificates trusted by this driver using 
`neo4j.driver(.., { trustedCertificates:['path/to/certificate.crt']}). This  is a security measure 
to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks. If you are just trying  Neo4j out and are not 
concerned about encryption, simply disable it using `encrypted="ENCRYPTION_OFF"` in the driver 
options. Socket responded with: DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

I've mapped the volumes as follows:

`/certificates` to the letsencrypt live folder for the domain `db.example.com`

Then I'm trying to connect to it via: `bolt://db.example.com:32771`

When i check via browser, the certificate being served is self-signed. I have try to add this certificate to the trusted certificates in windows but it didn't do anything at all.

Also added the path to the trusted certificates when instantiating the driver:

```
    this._driver = neo4j.driver(process.env.Neo4jUri, token, {
      encrypted: true,
      trustedCertificates: ['ssl/neo4j.crt'],
    });
```

I've also tried to copy the files within that certificate folder so that the appropriate files are named [as mentioned in this article.](https://medium.com/neo4j/getting-certificates-for-neo4j-with-letsencrypt-a8d05c415bbd)